# How to add custom dimension column in google analytics "User Explorer" view

Tags: google-analytics, explorer, dimension

I am working on ionic & angular application and implemented google analytics  for the same and **worked on "User Id" tracking** as well. I've **added custom dimension named "Environment"** in google analytics and I'm able to see it in "Behavior > Overview" tab when I select secondary dimension.

Now **I want to see "Environment" column with "User Id"** (i.e in "User Explorer"). So how can achieve it ?

By clicking on specific User ID I get whole information with custom dimension as well, I checked "Add Segment" as well but didn't find anything helpful there.  I don't want to click every user and find out "Environment" value for the same. So is there any way I can **add custom dimension column to "User Explorer" view and also add filters to identify users from specific environment** ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...
Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for this same implementation in Google Analytics, Want to display "email" which is a custom dimension that I've defined in GA. Can't find a place to do so. My GA property is of type **"Web"** and not **"Web and App"**

Answer (score 2):

So I think I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997964/google-analytics-custom-dimension-values-are-not-displayed-in-audience-user-e) and it's answer which states that this request is not a valid feature in Google Analytics.

As the answer also says, you can read more on this at: [User Explorer](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en)